# How to write an extension for the Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-extensions

The actual thing that I need is an effective Delete method for the entities. In other words I would like to be able to write

```
cntx.Orders.Where(item => item.Category == "Custom1").Delete();
```

and that is supposed to delete all the records from the table Orders where the Category column value is equal to "Custom1". I don't really care if it will do it right away or after calling cntx.SaveChanges(). And, yes, the query is supposed to be efficient, something like

```
DELETE FROM Orders WHERE Category = "Custom1"
```

I know about at least 3 extension libraries for the Entity Framework Core which advertise such abilities but non of them work for Android. Now, I'm thinking how difficult it actually is to write a Delete extension method myself. Can anybody help me with an example? Apparently I should be able to add something to the expression tree which will be called by the framework and in my turn I would generate "DELETE FROM Orders" and then "Where(item => item.Category == "Custom1")" would be replaced by the "WHERE Category = "Custom1""

So, apparently everything should start from

```
public static class QueryExtension {
   public static void Delete<T>(IQueryable<T> objThis) {
      // The big mystery is what to call here to ensure that "DELETE FROM [TableName]"
      // is entered to the right place of the expression tree and then
      // we somehow need to execute the complete statement here or delegate it to SaveChanges
   }
}
```

I sort of realize that translation of the expression tree into a SQL statement happens somewhere in the expression visitor. That is most likely wrapped into some kind of statement compiler of the Entity Framework. I have no idea where all those entry points to write an extension like I need.

Comment: What EF Core version are we talking about? Because there is no public extension point, so doing things like this would require digging into EFC internals, which differ between versions.

Comment: I don't want to rely on internal implementation anyway. If there are no public extension point I guess I better go other direction. Technically, the only thing I need is a translator of "where" expression into SQL statement and I saw some suggestions using reflection, I don't want that either. There everything starts from using of an instance of QueryCompiler even though it is a public class. I'd better create another instance of it but the constructor is very complex. An alternative could be finding a public expression visitor for translation.

Comment: Well, you request functionality not supported by EF Core, hence by definition you can't get public solution. The public EF way is load, remove, save changes.

Comment: I'm describing what overall I would like to achieve. As long as you are saying EF Core is not extendable I can rephrase my question. Does anybody know where to find a public library, preferably extendable, allowing to convert an expression tree to a SQL statement.

Comment: You can try [Linq To Db](https://github.com/linq2db)  and its EF Core integration [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore). They have the exact `Delete` extension as yours plus many others.

Comment: I saw that library. Tried it. On Android, in runtime, it throws platform not supported exception even though it installs fine. Looking for something else.